# yarn + ts-node: cannot find module fs

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, ts-node

I have Yarn workspaces with several packages (w1, w2, w3); w3 is using fs library.

I want to use `ts-node` to run w1 as follows:
`yarn workspace w1 start` where start is `node-ts src/index.ts`

However I get:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

This error comes from the w3 workspace;
simple compilation `tsc` in w3 directory works fine.

I tried installing `@types/node`, which works for tsc, but not for `ts-node`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a configuration that worked for me, in my `tsconfig.json` I have specified in the `typeRoots`:

```json
{  
  "compilerOptions": {
     "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

And in my package.json I have:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1"
  }
}
```

Also check that you have properly setup the references of the workplaces in the `tsconfig`.